# Error parsing attribute name

Tags: javascript, xhtml

The browser is saying there is an error in my javascript at this function, in my xhtml. If I remove this function the error disappears. For me this piece of code looks like perfect in syntax:

```
    function toAscii(text) {
        for (var i=0; i<text.length; i++) {
            var charCode = text.charCodeAt(i);
            var ascii = charCode.toString(2);
            console.log(ascii);
        }
    }
```

Chrome error:

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 19 at column 31: error parsing attribute name
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

Firefox error:

```
Erro no processamento de XML: formatação incorreta 
Posição: file:///C:/Users/Carlos/Desktop/ascii%20converter.xhtml
Número da linha 19, coluna 33:
                        for (var i=0; i<text.length; i++) { 
---------------------------------------------------^
```

---

This is the entire XHTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>ASCII Converter</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function converter() {
            var text = document.getElementById('texto').value;
            toAscii(text);
        }

        function toAscii(text) {
            for (var i=0; i<text.length; i++) {
                var charCode = text.charCodeAt(i);
                var ascii = charCode.toString(2);
                console.log(ascii);
            }
        }       
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    Texto (Entrada):<br/>
    <input id="texto" type="text"/><br/>
    ASCII (Saída):<br/>
    <input id="ascii" type="text"/><br/>
    <input type="button" id="botao" value="Converter" onclick="converter()"/><br/>  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Isn't the error on your XHTML?

Comment: Maybe. But if I remove this function the error disappears.

Comment: Did you try wrapping your js in a cdata node? I think XML requires that, but I'm not sure. Do you really need XHTML?

Comment: I don't really need xhtml. Maybe I will switch back to simple html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using xhtml and you have a `<` in your code you'll have to enclose your code in a cdata block

```
<script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
    function converter() {
        var text = document.getElementById('texto').value;
        toAscii(text);
    }

    function toAscii(text) {
        for (var i=0; i<text.length; i++) {
            var charCode = text.charCodeAt(i);
            var ascii = charCode.toString(2);
            console.log(ascii);
        }
    }       
]]></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

XHTML, strictly speaking, doesn't allow javascript to be stuck in the header the way one might to with HTML. As someone mentioned, it should be wrapped in a CDATA section. As a side note, the code as you've posted runs on my browser, but it's probably being lenient. Check out this reference for more information on xhtml and embedded css/javascript:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Properly_Using_CSS_and_JavaScript_in_XHTML_Documents